# Jquery - replace data with a chunk of html code with a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

So I have this piece of code:

```
<td>
     <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
       {% for client_id in  computer_client_id%}
          <option>{{client_id}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
       </select>
 </td>
```

I would like to execute this code in jquery so long I tried doing:

```
$("#level-2-none").html("<td><select class='selectpicker' multiple data-live-search='true'>{% for client_id in  computer_client_id%}<option>{{client_id}}</option>{% endfor %}</select></td>")
```

but it didn't work (not it all just did this small white block). if I do it in HTML it works fine. but I need to change the data in jquery with this code ^ how do I do it? I think that a big problem is the for loop.

Comment: Is that jquery in a separate js file? If so the jinja2 template engine won't work it there.

Comment: @jignatius No it's in the same js file

Comment: @jignatius Yeah

Comment: Try encasing the jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){     })`

Comment: @Dragonsnap it is inside it, it just has a LOT of data

Comment: @jignatius What do I suppose to do now?

Comment: @jignatius Yeah... I mean I really don't that the loop is applied in jquery

Comment: Have you checked html source to see if the jquery is being created? Are you sure that element with id `level-2-none` exists?

Comment: @jignatius yeah, definitely if I replace it with the number 1, for example, it works fine

Comment: Then I don't think the error is here. It's probably somewhere else in your javascript. Check for syntax errors, etc

Comment: @jignatius I am pretty sure I know what the problem is. Hand on

Comment: @jignatius Yeah.. the problem is adding the class to the select element at least on of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it was a bootstrap class so there were elements I couldn't and I had to inspect elements in order to see them on the site. Then I was able to check it in my code.